# What are some good examples where SQL's OUTER JOIN is used?

Tags: sql, join, left-join, outer-join

I often get asked the questions in an interview that "what is an outer join in SQL"?

While it can be answered, I wonder what might be some classic and good real life examples where a (LEFT) OUTER JOIN is used?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101343/what-is-the-purpose-or-use-case-for-an-outer-join-in-sql

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Northwind database on the Customers and Orders table.

Doing an inner join will only give you customers that have placed orders.

Doing an outer join will get *all* customers and orders for customers that have placed orders.

Answer (score 6):

To add to Robin Day's answer, you can also use a Left Outer Join to grab only customers who have NOT placed orders by checking for NULL.

```
SELECT *
FROM  Customer
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Order 
    ON Customer.CustomerId = Order.CustomerId
WHERE Order.CustomerId IS NULL
```

Answer (score 5):

Following is the visual represntation of the left outer join

```
SELECT <select_list>
FROM Table_A A
LEFT JOIN Table_B B
ON A.Key = B.Key
```

[image]

read more about joins in the below article 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins.aspx ( one of the best article must read )

Answer (score 4):

A `LEFT OUTER JOIN` can be used when you want all records from one table, as well as records from another table if any.

E.g., given table `User` and `Address`, where `Address` has a FK to `User` and there could be 0 or more addresses per user:

```
select *
from User u
left outer join Address a on u.UserID = a.UserID
```

This will ensure you get all `User` records, regardless of whether there was a corresponding `Address` record or not.

If you want to show all Users that do not have addresses, you can do this:

```
select *
from User u
left outer join Address a on u.UserID = a.UserID
where a.UserID is null
```

Answer (score 3):

Classic example is cutomers and orders.  Some customers have orders and others do not.  You want to show a list of customers with total sales.  So you do a left outer join from the customer to the order and get:

Customer A: $100;
Customer B: $0;
Customer C: $500

instead of:

Customer A: $100;
Customer C: $500

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example:

I need a list of all customers, with their vouchers, I also need the customers that never used vouchers.

```
SELECT *
FROM Customer
LEFT OUTER JOIN Voucher
 ON Customer.CustomerId = Voucher.CustomerId
```

Answer (score 1):

Get a list of all customers including any details of orders they have made. Some customers may not have made orders and therefore an INNER JOIN would exclude them from this list.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Customer
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Order
ON
    Customer.CustomerId = Order.CustomerId
```